# Travis CIでcpコマンドでファイルが作られていない

Tags: travis-ci, hugo

本当はやりたいことがあるのですが、試しにcpコマンドを書いてみました。

**.travis.yml**

```
script:
  - cp README.md TEMP.md
```

設定画面は下記のようになっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**ログ抜粋**

> This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not
>   allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables. If you require
>   sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml See
>   http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/
>   for details. $ rvm use default Using
>   /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551 $ ruby --version ruby 1.9.3p551
>   (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux] $ rvm --version rvm 1.26.10
>   (latest-minor) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal
>   Papis  [https://rvm.io/] $ bundle --version Bundler
>   version 1.7.6 $ gem --version
>   2.4.5 $ cp README.md TEMP.md
>
> The command "cp README.md TEMP.md" exited with 0.
>
> Done. Your build exited with 0.

gemやなんやらが動いているのが気になりますが（たぶん関係ない）、

> 2.4.5 $ cp README.md TEMP.md
>
> The command "cp README.md TEMP.md" exited with 0.
>
> Done. Your build exited with 0.

なのでうまくいってるようです。しかし特にGitHub上のmasterブランチに変化はありません。

### 追記：

[サイトをリニューアルした | kuune.org](http://kuune.org/text/2015/01/29/site-renewal/)

引用：

> 技術的な話をすると、Hugo という Go で作られた静的サイトジェネレーターを使って構築したものを GitHub Pages
>   でホストしていて、
>
> git push → Travis-CI でビルド → Travis-CI が gh-pages に push → 公開

HugoでできたサイトをCIでビルドしているとあります。
おもいっきり推測なのですが、Hugoはpublicというディレクトリの下にHTMLが作られるので、ディレクトリ構成を変えていることをビルドと呼んでいると思いました(publicディレクトリを消すとか）。そういった意味でcpコマンドを試してみたのですが、何か反映させる方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: あなたのローカルマシンでcpコマンドを実行したら、GitHub上のmasterブランチが変化するでしょうか？それと同じことです。

Comment: なるほど。質問に追記いたしました。本当にやりたいことがわかってもらえると意図が通じると思いましため。

Comment: 上記cpコマンドの結果をGitHub上のmasterブランチを反映させるという目的だけを果たすのであれば、pushが足りないだけのように思えてきました。　http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/　あたりを参照するのがヒントになりそうです。

Answer (score 1):

テストやビルドの結果、ソースが変更されてはいけないのでは無いでしょうか。
変更されたら、そのソースでテスト・ビルドしなければいけませんから、無限ループです。

Hugoの例だと、ビルドの成果物（ソースも公開したいのならば含めても構いませんが）をソースのリポジトリとは別の公開用のリポジトリへpushする物なのではないかと思います。